# C#: Firefox webdriver: How to download file to a specific folder

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

Good day.

I try to set up options for firefox webdriver for download to a specific foler. I put my code below. It's throws TypeInitializationException on last line.

How i can set default folder for file download and set that it should be without alert window?

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.folderList", 2);          firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.dir", Constants.DownloadFilesLocation);
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpeg");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/png");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/gif");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/bmp");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/tiff");
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define capability values as strings. Also, the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` should be defined as a comma-separated list:

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.folderList", "2");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", "false");
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.download.dir", Constants.DownloadFilesLocation);
firefoxOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/bmp, image/tiff");

Driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Also, check that the `Constants.DownloadFilesLocation` is a download directory path string.

Comment: For Chrome path accepted and works fine. I use FirefoxProfile.SetPreference, but it also doesn't works. File still downloads to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp`